# Liquibase throws Java `IllegalArgumentException` with message `URI is not hierarchical`

Tags: java, liquibase

I am trying to use [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) in a simple project.

In order to familiarize with the solution, I set up a simple Spring Boot project with database (PostgreSQL) connection and added the Liquibase dependency.

The dependencies in the `pom.xml` file are:

```xml
    [OMISSIS]

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Liquibase -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    [OMISSIS]
```

I create a `User.java` entity class as follows:

```java
package [OMISSIS].liquidemo.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Moreover, I create the `db.changelog-master.xml` file as indicated (directory `src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml`) and I generate the baseline changelog for the project. Up to this point there were no problems.

When I try to trigger Liquibase Update, I get the following error:

```
[OMISSIS]/java liquibase.integration.commandline.Main --driver org.postgresql.Driver --changeLogFile db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml --url jdbc:postgresql://[DATABASE_URL]:[DATABASE_PORT]/[DATABASE_NAME] --username [USERNAME] --password [PASSWORD] update
Starting Liquibase at [OMISSIS] CET (version 3.6.2 built at 2018-07-03 11:28:09)
Unexpected error running Liquibase: URI is not hierarchical
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
    at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:420)
    at liquibase.resource.FileSystemResourceAccessor.addRootPath(FileSystemResourceAccessor.java:51)
    at liquibase.resource.AbstractResourceAccessor.init(AbstractResourceAccessor.java:39)
    at liquibase.resource.FileSystemResourceAccessor.init(FileSystemResourceAccessor.java:44)
    at liquibase.resource.FileSystemResourceAccessor.<init>(FileSystemResourceAccessor.java:26)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:949)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:191)
    at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:129)

For more information, please use the --logLevel flag
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-liquibase/issues/4). As suggested [in this post](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-liquibase/issues/4#issuecomment-489592968), we can use the dependency (Gradle):

```
compile ("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.6.3") {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework'
}
```

which in my case translates to (Maven):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This solves the problem.